# List multiple models in class based list and detail views in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have these 4 models . There is a section where the user would be able to view all incomplete tasks. How would I go about displaying these using the ListView and DetailView ?
In all the examples in the django docs they always give an example just with one model. Can this be done using the CBV or are there alternatives?

Models

```
class task_a(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    task_complete = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    q1 = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    q2 = models.DateField()
    q3 = models.TimeField()
    q4 = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "task_a"
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task_a')
     def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.q1, self.q2, self.q3, self.q4,self.q5)


class task_b(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    task_complete = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    q1 = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    q2 = models.DateField()
    q3 = models.TimeField()
    q4 = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "task_b"
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task_b')
     def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.q1, self.q2, self.q3, self.q4,self.q5)


class task_c(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    task_complete = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    q1 = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    q2 = models.DateField()
    q3 = models.TimeField()
    q4 = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "task_c"
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task_c')
     def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.q1, self.q2, self.q3, self.q4,self.q5)


class task_d(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    task_complete = models.BooleanField(default=0)
    q1 = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    q2 = models.DateField()
    q3 = models.TimeField()
    q4 = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "task_d"
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('task_d')
     def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.q1, self.q2, self.q3, self.q4,self.q5)
```

Comment: What is the difference in these tasks? They all look the same.

Comment: the fields are different actually didnt put them in ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add extra context variables by overriding the `get_context_data()` function in your class:

```
class MultipleModelsListView(ListView):
    model = TaskA # Class names should use capitalized CamelCase

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(MultipleModelListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        kwargs.update({
            'taskb_list': TaskB.objects.all(), # or with some filter applied
            'taskc_list': TaskC.objects.all(),
            'taskd_list': TaskD.objects.all(),
        })
        return kwargs
```

This will give you, additional to the default context supplied by a `ListView`, the context variables `taskb_list`, `taskc_list` and `taskd_list` to iterate over.

You can iterate over these in your template like this:

```
{% for task in object_list %} {# default supplied by ListView #}
    {{ task.whatever }}
{% endfor %}
{% for task in taskb_list %}
    {{ task.whatever }}
{% endfor %} 
{# etc. #}
```

Comment: Hi @knbk.. I tried this, didnt get any errors but it did not render in my template.. 

I did it like this 

{% for taskb_list in object_list %}
<td>{{ taskb_list.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ taskb_list.created_by }}</td>
      ... .......

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your help. Sorry that I cant vote this up

Comment: @vvdect Glad it worked! Even if you can't upvote, accepting my answer would be much appreciated. ;)